# Why can't I deploy to Cloud Functions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I've been able to deploy for months and now suddenly this morning I am getting this error.

```
│ Error: Error while updating cloudfunction configuration: Error waiting for Updating CloudFunctions Function: Error code 3, message: Build failed: curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 
│ 
│ gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
│ tar: Child returned status 1
│ tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now; Error ID: 637fe2a4
│ 
│   with google_cloudfunctions_function.syncFiles,
│   on functions.tf line 396, in resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "syncFiles":
│  396: resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "syncFiles" {
│
```

This is the terraform configuration. We zip the directory and give this to cloud functions to deploy

```
data "archive_file" "source-zip" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "${path.root}/../dist/"
  output_path = "${path.root}/../dist/files/${var.app_name}.zip"
  excludes    = ["files/**"]
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "deploy-zip" {
  name       = "${var.app_name}/${var.app_name}-${data.archive_file.source-zip.output_md5}.zip"
  bucket     = "${var.env_name}-deploy"
  source     = "${path.root}/../dist/files/${var.app_name}.zip"
  depends_on = [data.archive_file.source-zip]
}

output "deploy_zip" {
  value = google_storage_bucket_object.deploy-zip.name
}
```

What could cause this error?

Is this an internal problem?

I have a ticket open with Google support but nothing useful yet.

Comment: Are you using the same user from what you used before when you were able to deploy the function successfully? If not, have you assigned the appropriate permission for this user? As per [official docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloudfunctions_function), it should have a `Cloud Functions Invoker` role.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please go to Cloud build, select your region, look at history/logs, that should tell you what is failing.

Possibly a package issue.